# Good resource for hadoop theory for beginners

Tags: hadoop

Can someone please suggest some good resources to study Hadoop fundamentals. More from Hadoop architecture and theory than actual coding. Where one can learn/read in depth about namenodes etc.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Hadoop had been there for some time, and there are a lot of resources in Google search. So, -1 for the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do)** by **Tom White** is the first thing which comes to my mind. Awesome piece of text and covers almost all the aspects.

Apart from this there some good links which cover individual things, like :

**1. [The Hadoop Distributed File System](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html)** : Covers stuff like Architecture, File I/O, Replication etc.

**2. [HDFS Architecture Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_design.html)** : Official HDFS architecture guide.

**3. [High Availability for the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/)** : If you need some         info on **HDFS HA**.

Comment: HDFS architecture page is moved [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopresources.html) is a consolidated list of some nice resources to Hadoop/MR.